# Getting a list of USB devices connected to an ESX _host_

Tags: java, vmware

I'm using vijava to manipulate an ESX host directly. The ESX host has several phones connected to it via USB, which I need to programmatically  attach to or detach from a specific VM for testing. I've worked out how to attach and detach devices without problem (there isn't much out there in terms of examples). However that requires knowing the device's name beforehand and potentially hard-coding it. So I'm looking for a way to get a list of the devices connected to the ESX host itself. With that I could iterate through them, choose one, and attach it to the VM without any foreknowledge of the device.

I've found a way to get a list of USB devices attached to a VM. I've also found a way to get a list of the default (non-USB) devices attached to the host. But I can't find anything in the model that looks like it provides a list of USB devices on the host. Does anyone know a way to get such?

Answer (score 0):

lsusb is available at the vSphere ESXi command line available through the "Troubleshooting Mode" on the ESXi host itself (see https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mYkhyx-BF_4/maxresdefault.jpg).  Historically vSphere has not made USB storage devices available for passthrough to VMs.  Since phones are storage devices as far as USB is concerned that means that although you will be able to list them at the command line in ESXi you won't see them available for a VM.  The reasons for this are buried in the bowels of the vSphere ESXi kernel.  While it's marginally possible that this changed after ESXi 6.7 shipped and that it is now supported in ESXi 7.0, I would be very surprised as USB (beyond keyboard and support for booting from internal SD cards) isn't a big ask of the Enterprise customers who determine which new features get prioritized.  Like everything else it could be enabled but it would require some effort from a kernel team that is busy with other features more central to their mission.  Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.